# how to create queries in phpmyadmin using stored procedure in visual basic 6?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vb6, xampp

i have a problem here with my very simple system that uses stored procedure and my database is in xampp(phpmyadmin, mysql)--this is the required database.

My questions are:

*Is it possible to create queries(append,update,select,delete) in xampp like those in Ms Access Query Tools?

*Is is possible to add, update, select, and delete records in xampp using stored procedure in vb6? (using parameters)

Databse using xampp made me confused! I hope you could help me.

Comment: [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is a GUI for MySQL.

Comment: Yes, you call stored procedures into MySQL from VB6 (not to "XAMPP" which is a collection of services, just to the 'M' which is the MySQL database) Read [the MySQL docs on stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html) to learn how to create and call them.

Comment: but we are only required the mysql service in xampp. Can this be possibl using the mysql in xampp?

Comment: You are misunderstanding what MySQL is and what XAMPP is. MySQL is the RDBMS (database service) and XAMPP is just an easy way of installing the Apache web server, MySQL RDBMS, and PHP together at once.  If you need a GUI query builder, that needs to be an additional client application which you connect to the MySQL as installed by XAMPP.  Here are some suggestions for GUI query builders. http://superuser.com/questions/177555/mysql-query-builder-like-access-has-in-design-view

Comment: An number of MySQL client applications (like the command line client, MySQL Workbench, Navicat, SequelPro, etc) can all connect to your MySQL service on XAMPP.

Comment: But we need to use mysql in xampp only. How about stored procedure in vb6 then add, delete records in mysql, is that possible?

Comment: ahhh using workbench, is this ok when i use vb6?they are compatible?

Comment: VB6 is just another client - it is completely unrelated to Workbench.  Use any tool necessary to execute your `CREATE PROCEDURE (...)` statements to build stored procedures.  VB6 will execute them, probably via ODBC using a `CALL` as in `CALL your_stored_procedure(...)`

Comment: One last thing, where i should create stored procedure?in the xampp mysql or in the vb6?

Comment: The stored procedure lives inside the database, so it should be created in XAMPP, just as you would create your database and its tables there.